# Facing issue to invoke delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I am facing issue to invoke delegate. Issue is that when I call `server1_d_u()` function it goes in endless loop while invoking the delegate.

Complete code is as under:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Nadeem_Library;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Live_Traffic_Monitor
{
    public partial class Live_Traffic : Form
    {

    public Live_Traffic()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class A
    {
    public static string server1Inapsuccessful = "N/A";
    public static string server1Inapfailure = "N/A";
    public static string server1Inaptime = "N/A";
    public static string server1Inaptps = "N/A";
    public static string server1diatps = "N/A";
    public static string server1diafirst = "N/A";
    public static string server1Diasuccessful = "N/A";
    public static string server1Diafailure = "N/A";
    public static string server1Diatime = "N/A";
    public static string server1EOCNsuccessful = "N/A";
    public static string server1EOCNfailure = "N/A";
    public static string server1EOCNtime = "N/A";
    public static string server1EOCNtps = "N/A";

    public static string fa0 = "", fa1 = "", fa2 = "", fa3 = "", fa4 = "", fa5 = "", fa6 = "";
    public static DateTime now;
    }

    private delegate void dserver1_traffic();

    Thread server1thread;

    int nRowIndex = 0;
    int rowindex = 0;

    private void server1_d_u()
    {
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
    this.Invoke(new dserver1_traffic(server1_d_u));
    }
    else
    {
    Health_Checks.SelectedTab = tabSERVER1;
    nRowIndex = DGV_SERVER1.RowCount - 1;
    DGV_SERVER1.Rows.Add(A.fa2.ToUpper(), A.server1Inaptime, A.server1Inapsuccessful, A.server1Inapfailure, A.server1Diatime, A.server1diatps, A.server1Diafailure, A.server1EOCNtime, A.server1EOCNsuccessful, A.server1EOCNfailure);
    rowindex = DGV_SERVER1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    DGV_SERVER1.Update();
    DGV_SERVER1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = nRowIndex;
    MessageBox.Show(A.fa2);
    }

    }

    private void button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string line;
    while (true)
    {
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\SERVER1_Stats\\Traffic.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    string[] a = line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    A.fa0 = a[0];
    A.fa1 = a[1];
    A.fa2 = a[2];
    A.fa3 = a[3];
    A.fa4 = a[4];
    A.fa5 = a[5];
    A.fa6 = a[6];

    server1thread = new Thread(() =>

    {
    server1_traffic();
    Action action = new Action(server1_d_u);
    this.BeginInvoke(action);
    });
    server1thread.Start();
    A.server1Inapsuccessful = "N/A";
    A.server1Inapfailure = "N/A";
    A.server1Inaptime = "N/A";
    A.server1Inaptps = "N/A";
    A.server1diatps = "N/A";
    A.server1diafirst = "N/A";
    A.server1Diasuccessful = "N/A";
    A.server1Diafailure = "N/A";
    A.server1Diatime = "N/A";
    A.server1EOCNsuccessful = "N/A";
    A.server1EOCNfailure = "N/A";
    A.server1EOCNtime = "N/A";
    A.server1EOCNtps = "N/A";

    A.fa0 = "";
    A.fa1 = "";
    A.fa2 = "";
    A.fa3 = "";
    A.fa4 = "";
    A.fa5 = "";
    }
    }
    file.Close();
    DGV_SERVER1.Rows.Clear();

    }



    }
    public void server1_traffic()
    {
    string AB = A.fa2.Substring(A.fa2.Length-1, 1).ToUpper();
    string sserver1_tra = Nadeem_Library.Class1.server1_traffic(A.fa0, A.fa1, A.fa4, A.fa5, AB);
    string[] a = sserver1_tra.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r","/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (a.Length > 10)
    {
    A.server1Inaptime = a[0];
    A.server1Inapsuccessful = a[1];
    A.server1Inapfailure = a[2];
    A.server1Inaptps = a[3];

    A.server1Diatime = a[4];
    A.server1diatps = a[5];
    A.server1diafirst = a[6];
    A.server1Diafailure = a[7];

    A.server1EOCNtime = a[8];
    A.server1EOCNsuccessful = a[9];
    A.server1EOCNfailure = a[10];
    A.server1EOCNtps = a[11];

    }
    }
    }
}
```

Complete code is given up. This code is working fine without using thread but my application is not responding while code is running. To solve this issue I add thread but if I use thread.join(); then again code is working fine but app is not responding. To catter this issue I use delegate as well action but fail. Kindly help in this regards
Can you help me to correct the issue?

Comment: Could you give us more context - what sort of app is this? Could you provide a [mcve] rather than just a single method? (Also, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions and think about using more easily-understandable names. That's nothing to do with the question per se, but it would definitely make the code easier to work with. I'd also use `Action` rather than your own custom delegate that has the same signature.)

Comment: Can you tell us the exact path of the loop?

Comment: Notice the difference between the names of the Framework's method/properties and your own. Yours are indecipherable to anyone other than yourself which makes it difficult for others to understand what's going on (and thus difficult to provide help). I suggest you take the time to read up on c# naming conventions..your future self will thank you